# Подключение к PostgreSQL на C/C++ в XCode с использованием SQL-вставок

Tags: xcode, macos, postgresql, c, c++

Собственно, вопрос: как подключиться к БД PostgreSQL 9.2 используя с/с++ в среде XCode (osx 10.8.2)?

upd. Ситуация следующая. Есть код, работающий под линукс, вот кусок, осуществляющий подключение:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    EXEC SQL include sqlca;

            EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION; 
            char ConnectionString [] = "login@192.168.1.1:5432";
            char Login [] = "login";
            char Password [] = "password";
            EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

            EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
                    int my_id;
                    char my_data[256];
                    int my_count;
                    char date1[10];
                     char date2[10];
            EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

     EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR SQLPRINT;

    int main() 
{

            EXEC SQL CONNECT TO :ConnectionString  USER :Login using :Password;

            if( sqlca.sqlcode != 0 || strncmp(sqlca.sqlstate,"00",2))
            {
                    printf("connect -- NoOK\n");
                    exit(-1);
            }
            else
            {
                    printf("connect --OK\n");   
                    menu();
            }   
            exec sql disconnect;
            printf("disconnect --OK\n");
    }
```

Сей код крайне желательно перенести под мак и запустить в XCode. В принципе, не обязательно именно данный код, достаточно реализовать аналогичную функциональность, но есть одна ключевая проблема - любые SQL-вставки XСode не распознаёт (т.е. всё, что начинается с EXEC). Как реализовать поддержку этих вставок в данной среде?

Comment: А вы в гугле смотрели? Первая же ссылка: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1138516/276994

Comment: Спасибо конечно за скорую реакцию, однако Вам не кажется странным, что вопрос задан на  ресурсе, где делятся _опытом_, а не ссылками в гугл? У Вас есть _опыт_ подключения к postgres в среде _xcode_? Если да - велкам в ответы, всегда рады; если нет - проходите, не задерживайтесь.

Comment: А я, наивный, думал, что здесь просто отвечают на вопросы.

Comment: Пока ни одного ответа на поставленный вопрос не последовало.